# "Ill met by Moonlight" quest: quest marker does not point to Sinding

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So, apparently I'm the first with this problem; I assume so because I've yet to find any mention of this particular bug.

I started this quest on a bit of a rough note as it is. I had to leave the jail and re-enter to get Sinding to even approach the bars. But once he did, all went well. He gave me the ring, transformed and fled from the cell. Now, I was doing another side-mission in the area of Falkreath before heading off to the nearest location I could fast-travel to near Bloated Man's Grotto. I entered, and spoke to the dying Hunter. Then I got the quest update to kill Sinding, but the marker indicated he was roaming out in the forest. So, I found him, but accidentally exited the dialog before I could tell him whether I was going to help him or not. This resulted in him fleeing to the Grotto where the quest continued as normal.

Now, I don't want the Savior's Hide armour, I wanted the Ring of Hircine. So I loaded my last (and only) save. I figured if it glitched similarly, I could just make sure not to exit the dialog with Sinding before telling him I was on his side. But, the bug has changed somehow. NOW instead of roaming the world aimlessly, waiting for me to find him, the quest marker indicates he's in the jail cell. Here is where the bug is different from any I've looked up. The MARKER is in the cell, but Sinding HIMSELF is NOT.

I've reloaded, and reloaded, and reloaded, changing the path I take to the Grotto and such (even choosing not to do the side-mission I mentioned earlier), all to only have the marker indicate the middle of the Falkreath jail cell everytime since. I have no idea what to do, as now I'm simply stuck with the damned Curse Ring of Hircine.

Comment: Is it possible the marker is just messed up and he is still in the wilderness? Did you try going to the area you found him the first time? My recommendation is to ignore the marker completely and see if you can find him in the wilderness.

Comment: You know, I considered that when I tried using Clairvoyance to determine the direction of my quest destination. It lead me to the jail, but once I got down to the room the cell is in, Clairvoyance told me I didn't have a path to follow. So, I'm not sure what to think, but it's worth a try.

Comment: This is four years old, so you probably don't care anymore, but if you're on PC you should be able to solve this with a console command without much trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to the grotto and do everything that should be done and the quest should still work. I had this glitch with another quest but if you just do the quest as normal it will allow you to complete the quest and receive either the ring of hircine or the savior's hide.

Answer (score 0):

I have nearly the same problem except that I told him I'd help him then the marker disappeared so I followed him to a giants camp and he disappeared and left me with the ring and a bunch a angry giants. But the worst part is I can't take it off so I can't use my heath ring like I'd use normally.

Try following paths near by and killing any hunters that you might find hunting on the roads.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too. So I went to the Bloated man's grotto, and he wasn't there, but when I came out, the quest marker had moved.  It was near Riverwood.  I went there, and Sinding was walking down the street.  I talked to him and was able to finish the quest.

Comment: This doesn't provide an answer to the question. To recieve clarification from the asker, make sure you have enough reputation to comment on other people's posts.

Answer (score 0):

To take off the ring, either help or kill Sinding. Turn yourself into a werewolf; that removes ALL armor and jewelry. After killing the hunters then speed up time by about 4-5 hours. When you become human again the ring is removed. You can now put on your former jewelry. If the marker is stuck on the jail go to where you found Hircine and kill him. His ghost will then emerge. Go on about the quest as if you talked to Sinding.